# Python, Tkinter - How to run 'shelve.close ()' when exiting the gui program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, shelve

I have a simple gui(tkinter) program that writes data to a file. Uses shelve.
How to run shelve.close () when I want to disable the program?

Comment: Hi @MrKorni, could you please add more detail to your question? Like the code you've written so far? That would be helpful for us to help you out!

Comment: The code is long and in a different language

Comment: What does it mean in a different language? Please consider that your question maybe helpful to others as well!

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. However, I believe that I have at least as many details as I need to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way of closing something *no-matter-what-happens* is to use context managers:

```
with shelve.open(...) as myshelve:
    # ALL YOUR CODE HERE
    root.mainloop()
```

This guarantees that shelve.close() will be called, even when you get any exceptions in the code.

It is also the [recommended way in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#shelve.open):

> Do not rely on the shelf being closed automatically; always call `close()` explicitly when you don’t need it any more, or **use `shelve.open()` as a context manager**.

Alternatively, since you're using tkinter, you can use the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` event:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def when_window_is_closed():
    myshelve.close()
    root.destroy()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", when_window_is_closed)
root.mainloop()
```

This method is worse because it depends on tk firing the event. Use the context manager method instead to cover all grounds.

Comment: Do I need to "import tkinter as tk"? Can I "from tkinter import *"?

Comment: @MrKorni you can do whatever you want. I prefer to use `import tkinter as tk` to prevent **global namespace polution** - that way all names from tkinter are contained inside the `tk` module object, instead of scattered in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The `mainloop` call stops when your GUI stops. If you want to run some code after the GUI exits just put it after `mainloop()`.

```
root.mainloop() # starts the GUI and waits for the GUI to close
shelve.close() # do something after the GUI closes
```